# SwashBuckle Swagger-UI Example Request for HTTP GET Method with FromQuery Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I've managed to add examples to my Web API with `SwashBuckle.AspNetCore` and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters` for POST methods:

**DTO**

```
public class ExampleDTO
{
    public string MyFoo { get; set; }
}
```

**Example Request**

```
public class ExampleDTOExample : IExamplesProvider<ExampleDTO>
{
    public ExampleDTO GetExamples()
    {
        return new ExampleDTO()
        {
            MyFoo = "bar"
        };
    }
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
[SwaggerOperation(
    Summary = "...",
    Description = "...",
    OperationId = "PostFoo"
)]
[SwaggerResponse(200, "Returns ...", typeof(int))]
[HttpPost]
[Route("post-foo")]
public ActionResult<int> PostFoo([FromBody]ExampleDTO request)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This work perfectly fine. When I click the "try it out" button, I have "bar" as prefilled value for the property foo.

However, when I'm trying to do the same for a GET request, e.g., with parameters from query like this, the text box is not prefilled with the value "bar":

[image]

```
public class ExampleDTO
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "foo")]
    public string MyFoo { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
[SwaggerOperation(
    Summary = "...",
    Description = "...",
    OperationId = "GetFoo"
)]
[SwaggerResponse(200, "Returns ...", typeof(int))]
[HttpGet]
[Route("get-foo")]
public ActionResult<int> GetFoo([FromQuery]ExampleDTO request)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

How can I force the text box to be prefilled with the example value? So far I've found a solution for specifying a default value which is not want I want. I only want to use attributes for a default value in Swagger UI.

Comment: I found a couple of intresting issues reported around examples:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5776
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3233

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the value you see on:
[image]

That is not the example but the default value.

---

Here is something that I've done in the past:

```
"/attrib/{payId}": {
    "get": {
        "tags": [
            "Attribute"
        ],
        "operationId": "Attribute_Get",
        "consumes": [],
        "produces": [
            "application/json",
            "text/json",
            "text/html"
        ],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "payId",
                "in": "path",
                "required": true,
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32",
                "default": 123
            }
        ]
```

http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Attribute#/Attribute/Attribute_Get

[image]
[image]

---

Here is another case with both default and example

```
"Company": {
    "required": [
        "Id",
        "MyId"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "Id": {
            "description": "The Unique Company ID",
            "example": "123",
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32",
            "default": 456
        },
        "MyId": {
            "example": 123,
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
        },
```

http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#/Company/Company_Get2

You can see that the example is not what is shown in the Swagger UI

Comment: Link is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML comments for this purpose.

> Since May 2018, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore supports adding examples via XML comments.
>
> Source: https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters/blob/master/README.md#request-example

But firstly, you enable XML **Documentation file** for your project. You can enable it  in project's properties.

[image: project properties]

After you must include XML comments to Swagger in **Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        ...

        // This path can be different on your project.
        var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "WebApi.xml");
        c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);

        ...

    });

    ...
}
```

After, you must add XML example to DTO's property

```
public class ExampleDTO
{
    /// <example> MyFooExampleValue </example>
    public string MyFoo { get; set; }
}
```

Result is like as below:

[image: result1]

"Try it out"'s result:

[image: result]

---

Note: Not only in the DTO, you can also write XML comment directly to the API

> And soon (April 2020, once my Swashbuckle.AspNetCore PR has been released) you'll be able to add examples for primitive types on the querystring too, e.g.

```
/// <param name="id" example="123">The product id</param>
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Product GetById(int id)
```

---

For more information you can visit these links:

[Using XML Comments As Web API Documentation With Swagger](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-xml-comments-as-web-api-documentation-with-swagger/)

[Request example of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters/blob/master/README.md#request-example)